# Continuous background ajax call keeping session alive

Tags: php, ajax, session

I've got some AJAX which checks every 5 seconds if there are overdue reminders on my website. The php script which it calls uses the php session and since implementing this users are never logged out after inactivity if they have the site open in their browser, because the session never expires.

I don't want to make the php session expire after a fixed time regardless of activity because I don't want to interrupt any work a user may be in the middle of either.

With that in mind, what could be a solution for this issue?

Comment: sending ajax request to the sever after every 5 seconds is a bad practice, its more like you are DDosing your own server, rather use websockets, or http long pulling

Comment: Store the timestamp of when they last did something on the site into the session. Then check the difference between that and the current time, whenever they do something again that considers “activity”. If to much time has passed, ask them to login again.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Thanks for the advice, see my question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116380/workaround-instead-of-using-websockets-ajax-long-pulling

Comment: @CBroe That seems like it should work